# regex/regular expression 'OR'

Tags: html, .net, regex, email

I have struggled on this for a while, can you please give some hints...

In outlook emails, we could have forwarded emails' information in the email body as:

```
From: Jackson, Peter
Sent: Tuesday, 26 March 2013 08:25 PM
To: **Match, Me**; GGG
Cc: AAA, BBB; CCC, DDD; EEE, FFF
Subject: FW: Good Morning
```

or

```
From: Jackson, Peter
Sent: Tuesday, 26 March 2013 08:25 PM
To: AAA; GGG
Cc: BBB; **Match, Me**; DDD; EEE, FFF
Subject: FW: Good Morning
```

Now I would like to get the DateTime in 'Sent' if there is a 'Match, Me' in either 'To' or 'Cc' list.

The Regex now I have is:

```
(<b>)?Sent:(</b>)?\s(?<MatchDateTime>[A-Z][a-z]{5,8},\s[0-9]{1,2}\s[A-Z][a-z]{2,9}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9{1,2}:[0-9][0-9]\s[A-Z]{2})(<br\s?/?>)?(\\r\\n)*?(<b>)?To:(</b>)?\s.[^<]*?(Match, Me).*?(<br\s?/?>)?(\\r\\n)*?(<b>)?Cc:(</b>)?\s.[^<]*?(Match, Me).*?(<br\s?/?>)(\\r\\n)*
```

Here is some example text:

```
<span lang=\"EN-US\" style=\"font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"\"> BBB, AAA [mailto:AAA.BBB@ccc.com.au]\r\n<br>\r\n<b>Sent:</b> Tuesday, 26 March 2013 5:23 PM<br>\r\n<b>To:</b> **Match, Me**; DDD; EEE<br>\r\n<b>Cc:</b> EEE, ZZZ; GGG, FFF<br>\r\n<b>Subject:</b> RE: Good Morning<o:p></o:p></span>
```

or

```
<span lang=\"EN-US\" style=\"font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif"\"> BBB, AAA [mailto:AAA.BBB@ccc.com.au]\r\n<br>\r\n<b>Sent:</b> Tuesday, 26 March 2013 5:23 PM<br>\r\n<b>To:</b> UUU, AAA, DDD; EEE<br>\r\n<b>Cc:</b> Match, Me; ZZZ; GGG, FFF<br>\r\n<b>Subject:</b> RE: Good Morning<o:p></o:p></span>
```

My Regex can only match one condition (in To list or Cc list) but not both, can you please help, thanks!

Comment: Don't parse HTML/XML with RegEx. Use XML/HTML parser instead. Such as [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) or [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Generally speaking you're looking for the pipe character http://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/8xMAm/ - as you may know both JS and C# use the same Regex standard, so the regex strings are compatible across the two. But using a single regex in this way seems way too complicated - break it up into a few simpler parts, the few ms extra of performance you might be getting with this can't be worth how impossible this code will be for the next coder to modify.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. As this is a new functionality to the existing work, unfortunately I have to stick on using Regex.Matches in C#, the only option to me might be the Regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
(\<b\>)?Sent:(\</b\>)?\s(?<MatchDateTime>[A-Z][a-z]{5,8},\s[0-9]{1,2}\s[A-Z][a-z]{2,9}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9][0-9]\s[A-Z]{2}).*?(To|Cc):(\</b\>)?\s[^<]*?(Match, Me)
```

First, I think it's better to escape all `<` and `>` characters because they are used in the regex syntax a lot. After the date matching group I added a non-greedy `.*?` to read the input until the first `To` or `Cc` is met. Then it reads until it matches `Match, Me`.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. You post is very close to the answer, however, after trying that, I've found a bug:
If we have
    <b>Sent:</b> Tuesday, 26 March 2013 5:23 PM<br>\r\n<b>To:</b>DDD; EEE<br>\r\n<b>Cc:</b> EEE, ZZZ; GGG, FFF<br>\r\n<b>Subject:</b> RE: Good Morning<o:p></o:p></span>**SOME TEXT IN HERE**Match, Me

The regex can match the whole text, however, the Match, Me is not in either To or Cc list.

Comment: Not sure I have explain it clearly: in an email somewhere else other than this information block, we can also have the matching 'Match, Me' (i.e. in someone's signature). The regex matches start from a 'Sent' and go through any text then stops at 'Match, Me'. Can we only do a matching within that email's information block?

Comment: I finally used a different way to avoid this bug, but your regex do helped me a lot and made mine simpler. Thanks for that!